# Looping variables

Tags: perl, scripting

I'm working with perl to make a script that will work with Dot products/assorted vector math. I've got a working script ( Still very much in progress/needs refinement ) that will do what I ask.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Math::Vector::Real;
use 5.010;
use Math::Trig;

my $source = "./IN";

my $out = "./OUT";

open(IN, '<', $source) or die "Couldn't open $source: $!\n";
open(OUT, '>', $out) or die "Couldn't open $out: $!\n";

my(@data);
while (<IN>) {
    push @data, [ split ];
}

my $v;
my $u;

$v = V(0, 0, 0); 
$u = V(0, 0, 0);

my $i = 0;

sub maths {
        my $dot = $v * $u;
        my $mag1 = (sqrt ((@$v[0])**2 + (@$v[1])**2 + (@$v[2])**2 ));
        my $mag2 = (sqrt ((@$u[0])**2 + (@$u[1])**2 + (@$u[2])**2 ));
        my $prefinal = acos( ( $dot ) / ( $mag1 * $mag2 ) );
        my $degrees = ( ( 180 / 3.14159 ) * ( $prefinal ) );
        return ($degrees);
}

my $ref1 = $data[$i][0];
my $ref2 = $data[$i][1];
my $ref3 = $data[$i][2];
my $ref4 = $data[$i+1][0];
my $ref5 = $data[$i+1][1];
my $ref6 = $data[$i+1][2];

$v->[0] = $ref1;
$v->[1] = $ref2;
$v->[2] = $ref3;

$u->[0] = $ref4;
$u->[1] = $ref5;
$u->[2] = $ref6;

my $result = maths;

print "$result\n";
```

A lot of stuff in the script is vestigial and for ease to follow (For me). 
What I desire it to do, is to have the script rotate through each line of the input file and perform the calculations on it. 
Something akin to having :

```
foreach $i (@data) {

my $ref1 = $data[$i][0];
my $ref2 = $data[$i][1];
my $ref3 = $data[$i][2];
my $ref4 = $data[$i+1][0];
my $ref5 = $data[$i+1][1];
my $ref6 = $data[$i+1][2];

$v->[0] = $ref1;
$v->[1] = $ref2;
$v->[2] = $ref3;

$u->[0] = $ref4;
$u->[1] = $ref5;
$u->[2] = $ref6;

my $result = maths;

print "$result\n";
}
```

Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Note that the module will calculate the magnitude of the vectors as well, so `my $mag1 = abs $v; my $mag2 = abs $u;`. In fact, if all you need is the angle between the vectors then the `maths` subroutine is just `atan2($v, $u) * 180 / 3.14159`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, most of the functionality of your program is provided by the [`Math::Vector::Real`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Vector::Real) module that you're already using

It looks like you want the angle in degrees between successive pairs of 3D vectors in your file. This code creates vectors from each line in the file until there are two vectors in `@pair`, and then uses `atan2` to calculate the angle between them. `DEG_PER_RAD` is precalculated as a constant from the value of `atan2(1,1)` which is **π ÷ 4** by definition

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Vector::Real;

use constant DEG_PER_RAD => 45 / atan2(1, 1);

my ( $source, $out ) = qw/ IN OUT /;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $source or die qq{Unable to open "$source" for input: $!\n};
open my $out_fh, '<', $out    or die qq{Unable to open "$out" for output: $!\n};
select $out_fh;

my @pair;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {

    push @pair, V(split);

    if ( @pair == 2 ) {
      my $degrees = atan2(@pair) * DEG_PER_RAD;
      print "$degrees\n";
      shift @pair;
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

To  do the calculation for every possible pair of vectors, it is simplest to read the whole of the file into an array of vectors and process them from there with two nested loops

This code demonstrates. Insert it after the `select` call in the original program. It labels each line of output with the two array indices that gave rise to the angle

```
my @data;
push @data, V(split) while <$in_fh>;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#data-1 ) {
    for my $j ( $i+1 .. $#data ) {
        my $degrees = atan2(@data[$i,$j]) * DEG_PER_RAD;
        print "[$i,$j] $degrees\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to edit slightly to make it work (Awaiting peer review), but it did. I had read about the atan function, but it wasn't clearly explained so I did it the hard way. Learned a thing or two along the way. Thanks!

Comment: However, is there any way to make it so it computes the angles starting at each line to every other line? I tried some nested foreach loops, but to no avail. I.e., For every line, compute angles. Go to the next line, and compute angles, until the end of the file.

Comment: @jcklasseter: Okay I've added some code to do what I think you want. Please explain the change that you had to make, as I don't see anything wrong with my code as it stands

Comment: On my mac, the nested atan has to have (@data[$i,$j]) written as (@data[$i], @data[$j]). Strict also complains and makes me change @data to $data in there as well. Also, the Output file is opened for input. For whatever reasons, my changes didn't make it through peer review.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
my $v = V( @{ $data[$i+0] } );
my $u = V( @{ $data[$i+1] } );
```

---

Cleaned up:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Trig         qw( acos );
use Math::Vector::Real qw( V );

sub maths {
    my ($v, $u) = @_;
    my $dot = $v * $u;
    my $mag1 = sqrt( $v->[0]**2 + $v->[1]**2 + $v->[2]**2 );
    my $mag2 = sqrt( $u->[0]**2 + $u->[1]**2 + $u->[2]**2 );
    my $prefinal = acos( $dot / ( $mag1 * $mag2 ) );
    my $degrees = ( 180 / 3.14159 ) * $prefinal;
    return $degrees;
}

{
    my @data = map { V( split ) } <>;
    for my $i (0..$#data-1) {
        for my $j ($i+1..$#data) {
            my $maths = maths(@data[$i, $j]);
            print("$i,$j: $maths\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Or with Borodin's alternate method:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Trig         qw( acos atan2 );
use Math::Vector::Real qw( V );

use constant DEG_PER_RAD => 45 / atan2(1, 1);

{
    my @data = map { V( split ) } <>;
    for my $i (0..$#data-1) {
        for my $j ($i+1..$#data) {
            my $maths = atan2(@data[$i, $j]) * DEG_PER_RAD;
            print("$i,$j: $maths\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl ./IN >./OUT
```

Comment: @jcklasseter, Updated as per your comment.